# Correct usage of infinitives

Tags: infinitives, gerunds, complements

I am not sure about the usage of *infinitives* in this sentence:

> Finally, one of the accused confessed *to have* forged the director's
>   signature on the report.

Could anyone explain correct usage?

Answer (score 5):

You seem to have confused the *to* particle used in certain infinitive constructs with *to* used as a preposition.

In English, the phrasal verb ***confess to*** takes the *-ing* form of the verb as its complement, not a bare infinitive as you have used here.

- He confessed to forging the signature.
- He confessed to having forged the signature.

This acts as the head of its own verb phrase (VP), and is effectively a noun.  When you use an *-ing* form as a noun, it is sometimes called  a gerund.  Notice how you can swap in a real noun:

- He confessed to the crime.
- So you would confess to yesterday’s robbery?

There is also a non-phrasal use of *confess*, as distinct from the phrasal verb *confess to*:

- He confessed his sin.

Comment: @ tchrist: So here in this question gerund appears in the picture rather than infinitives? Am i right?

Comment: +1 Notice that *he confessed his sin* is a slightly different construction.

Comment: Notice the difference now that we know the difference between _forging_ the present participle and _forging_ the gerund. Terminology makes everything clear, [Chinese-English ahead:] isn't it?

Comment: @StoneyB: I just checked my Collins-COBUILD _Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs_ but couldn't find _confess to_ listed. Where is it listed as a phrasal verb? I checked the [Internet](http://www.english-for-students.com/Phrasal-Verbs-C.html) as well, but came up blank. _Confess to_ seems to be merely an idiom with a synonymous phrasal verb: _own up_.

Comment: @BillFranke The OED has it as a phrasal verb: “6. *intr.* ***confess to*** (a thing): To plead guilty to (a charge), own to (a fault or weakness); to admit, acknowledge. With *indirect pass.”*

Comment: @tchrist: Thank you for the reference. One of these days I'll reinstall my OED on my XP Pro machine.